# jQuery plugin or jQuery with css for popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

[image]

I need to get this kind of popup using Jquery, please suggest Jquery plugin or any sample. I cant find a idea to start this.

Comment: You were vague, I assume that's why you got the negative vote. If you aren't real sure how to do advanced things to make this happen I would suggest you look into Lightbox or Highslide. Highslide is very cool in that it can display lots of types of data inside a window of any size you specify without you having to learn much code. If you'd really like a nice custom solution you will need the jQuery/Javascript solutions below with some learning involved

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" rel="popover" data-popover-content="#myPopover">My Popover</a>

<div id="myPopover" class="hide">

   <div class="left_box">
     <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</p>
     <p><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</p>
     <p><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</p>
   </div>

   <div class="right_box">
     <p>Audit Logs</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popover {width:400px;}
.left_box {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.right_box {
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
            return clone;
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  });

});
```

Please include jQuery and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to have this specific layout?

Maybe you could start out using [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)  and edit a little to fill it with your links.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the lighweight Bootstrap Tooltip or Popover. They come with BootstrapJS. See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp

Implementation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
```

In any element

```
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Content"
```

In your case you will need to set popover parameters to accept html

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
           html: true,
        }); 
    });
```

@Edit

Or you can try WebUI
https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover

Comment: I cant use bootstrap here.

Comment: M , yes, seems this one will work, but i cant find a code sample for thiss.